# Copying data from one s3 bucket to another s3 bucket of different account in fast manner, just using access_id, secret_access_key cred of both

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, distcp

I have access_key, access_id for both of the aws bucket belong to a different account. I have to copy data from one location to another, is there a way to do it faster.

I have tried map-reduced-based distcp that does not provide satisfactory performance.

Comment: what does map reduce have to do with this? There is nothing to map / reduce here. In what way does the performance not satisfy? If you have two different sets of credentials there is nothing other than downloading with first credentials and then uploading with the other ones. If you control either of the buckets, you can enable the other account to actually read / write to your bucket so that one set of credentials can access both buckets at the same time, then you can do "normal" s3 copy operations.

Comment: [distCP](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-distcp/DistCp.html) can do a distributed copy on Hadoop based Clusters, there's also a specific AWS version called [s3DistCP](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/UsingEMR_s3distcp.html) which might conceivably be used here.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to copy data between Amazon S3 buckets in different accounts is to **use a single set of credentials that has permission to read from the source bucket and write to the destination bucket**.

You can then use these credentials with the `CopyObject()` command, which will copy the object between the S3 buckets **without the need to download and upload the objects**. The copy will be fully managed by the Amazon S3 service, even if the buckets are in different accounts and even different regions. The copy will not involve transferring any data to/from your own computer.

If you use the AWS CLI `aws s3 cp --recusive` or `aws s3 sync` commands, the copies will be performed **in parallel**, making very fast copies of the objects.

There are two ways to perform a copy:

**Push**

- Use a set of **credentials from the Source account** that has permission to read from the source bucket
- Add a **Bucket Policy on the destination bucket** that permits Write access for these credentials
- When performing the copy, use `ACL=bucket-owner-full-control` to assign ownership of the object to the destination account

OR

**Pull**

- Use a set of **credentials from the Destination account** that has permission to write to the destination bucket
- Add a **Bucket Policy on the source bucket** that permits Read access for these credentials
- (No ACL is required because "pulling" the file will automatically give ownership to the account issuing the command)